# Ubuntu Audio crackling using logitech usb audio even after formatting

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, logitech

hello I have a serious problem it turns out that last Wednesday I got a partial update but when I restarted the sound it was distorted and crackling in my usb audio and I thought that formatting was the problem but when I finished formatting Ubuntu the audio is also distorted and crackling I used a Headphone and the audio sounds normal but in my logitech it works worse distorted audio and crackling and it's not a problem with the sound card since in Windows 11 the audio works very well I don't know what's wrong with my Ubuntu that the audio sounds distorted and cracking

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu? What does this statement from your question mean? when I finished formatting Ubuntu

Comment: 20.04 is my ubuntu versión How do I send an audio to show the problem

Comment: Please answer the question about what this means. when I finished formatting Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by changing the PulseAudio default sampling rate to 48000

`sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

Find these two lines

```
; default-sample-rate
; alternate-sample-rate
```

Remove the starting `;`  and set the values to 48000

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

Save the file, exit and restart pulse audio with `pulseaudio --kill`

Comment: I did this and it solved the problem thank you very much I will reformat to solve it again

Comment: What does reformat again mean?

Comment: Erase the entire disk and reinstall the system

Comment: Formatting and installing is NOT the same thing. They're used interchangeably in Brazil but it's wrong, period. So, avoid that mistake in the future.

Comment: ok i will I will try to avoid mistake it