# USB connected speakers sound distorted

Tags: usb

Hello I am having issues with my speakers connected through a usb cable to my computer.  They used to work for almost two years but now they sound distorted when I play music though them.  I know the speakers are fine because I have windows 10 installed on the same computer and they sound fine when I am just using windows.  When this started I had to run some commands in the terminal because the music player clementine was not playing my audio tracks at all but I cannot remember the error message or command I ran to fix that.  I was hoping someone could help me here because Googling did not solve this issue.
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1399388/1164424) solution.

Windows users can try disabling enhancements:

Winkey+R > type "mmsys.cpl" > OK > Speakers > Properties > Enhancements tab > uncheck "Disable all enhancements" > Apply > OK

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: In order to answer the OP's question you must provide a clear answer and relevant information. Keep trying.

Comment: @kwjamesblond My mistake, please see my edit.